# How to make Apache keep the connection after the request is finished?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, keepalive

So that subsequent request can still use the current connection.

Comment: You should accept the answer that best answered your question. You can do this by clicking the white check in front of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [`KeepAlive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive) option controls whether connections are kept open after a request. [`KeepAliveTimeout`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout) controls how long Apache will wait for a subsequent request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
KeepAlive On
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive

Answer (score 0):

According to the Official Apache Documentation, it would depend on the programming of the "thing" connecting to the apache server.  Thus HTTP/1.0 source programming will have some difficulty in doing what you are asking....whereas HTTP/1.1 protocol programming will make it easier to make this happen.

"
For HTTP/1.0 clients, Keep-Alive connections will only be used if they are specifically requested by a client. In addition, a Keep-Alive connection with an HTTP/1.0 client can only be used when the length of the content is known in advance. This implies that dynamic content such as CGI output, SSI pages, and server-generated directory listings will generally not use Keep-Alive connections to HTTP/1.0 clients. For HTTP/1.1 clients, persistent connections are the default unless otherwise specified. If the client requests it, chunked encoding will be used in order to send content of unknown length over persistent connections.
"